# ST_Union in Apache Sedona

Tags: sql, st-union

I'm trying to merge some polygons with [ST_Union](https://sedona.apache.org/api/sql/Function/?h=st_union#st_union) using Apache Sedona on a databricks cluster.

```
%sql
SELECT  Polygon_Name
       ,ST_Union(Polygon_Boundary) AS Polygon2_Boundary
FROM tbl_polygon
GROUP BY Polygon_Name
```

I get an "Error in SQL statement: AssertionError: assertion failed".  My assumption on this is because `ST_Union` in Sedona takes two arguments `ST_Union(Poly1, Poly2)` and is incapable of taking an array unlike other implementations of `ST_Union` (PostGIS).

I've checked the Sedona API materials and they indicate two arguments in their example, but thought I would ask in case some detail is missing in documentation and any thoughts on possible work around.

Comment: This works if I have LineStrings but not for MultiLineStrings.  Anyone got a solution?
IllegalArgumentException: Operation does not support GeometryCollection arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use Sedona myself but a quick look at the documentation shows that a function [ST_Union_Aggr](https://sedona.apache.org/archive/api/sql/GeoSparkSQL-AggregateFunction/?h=st_union#st_union_aggr) exists and seems to do what you need:

```sql
%sql
SELECT  Polygon_Name
       ,ST_Union_Aggr(Polygon_Boundary) AS Polygon2_Boundary
FROM tbl_polygon
GROUP BY Polygon_Name
```

Comment: Cheers, missed that one last night when I was wading through the options.